# How to add another volume to Linux if /dev/xvda through /dev/xvdz in use?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

I have a scenario where my linux machine is already using disks attached from /dev/xvda through /dev/xvdz. (I have a raid 10 of the ephemerals, a root drive, and an attached EBS volume) I need to add another EBS volume to this server. Is there any other device reference I can use to attach it? I am not familiar enough with this device reference feature to know what I can alter in the name to attach it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to locate more information on this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html

I used /dev/xvdba as a new device reference. This solved my problem.